# Updating resources in installed android application

Tags: android, android-studio

I've created a webview app which floats a html file that's inserted into the app(assets folder). Is there anyway to update this html file without updating the apk file?

I won't be uploading this app to play store. I'll be putting the html file in my web server so that the app can detect if there is a new html version and downloads the html file and replaces it.

Answer (score 2):

All resources/assets included in apk are final and cannot be edited at runtime.

You'll need to store new html files in your apps data directory (doesn't require any permissions) and use html from assets as a fallback.